# What should I do after the acceptance of a paper in supercomputing (Springer journal)?

Tags: publications, online-publication, springer

One week ago, my paper has been accepted and I received the following email:

```
You will be contacted about proofs and offprints in due course by our Manufacturing Department.
```

What should I do ? and it take time to publish my paper ?

Comment: All you need do is wait to be contacted. Yes it takes time.

Comment: Of course it takes time to publish your paper.

Comment: Celebrate or get ready to pay the publication fees, or both.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous answers. Now that your paper has been accepted, all you have to do is wait. If you are wondering about the time it takes to publish a paper after acceptance, you can get an approximate idea by visiting the journal website and checking the public record of a dozen of published papers. That is, the time between Accepted and Published.